# How to know the time taken by a target to execute in ant

Tags: java, ant

Is there a way to know the time taken by a target to execute and store that time in a     property in ant script. I have gone through tstamp and stopwatch but I am not getting the proper result.
   Example:

```
 <target name ="test">
   .....
   .....
  </target>
```

I want to know the time taken to execute by the target "test".

Comment: Have you tried `ant -v`?

Comment: I want to set the value of time taken by a target to execute in a property hence not tried with ant -v. This property value is to be passed to other targets

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned the [`stopwatch`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/stopwatch_task.html) task contained in [Ant Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/).

I had no problems to use it. First you define a stopwatch assigning a name. At the end of the target you use the `total` stopwatch action. The elapsed time is then stored into a property with the same name you used for creating the stopwatch.

```
<project name="Stopwatch">
  <!--
    Import Ant Contrib
  -->
  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>

  <!-- 
    Demonstrates the use of the stopwatch task.
    Creates a stopwatch named "timer1", do some work and then take the total
    time. The time is then stored in property "timer1".    
  -->
  <target name="teststopwatch">
    <stopwatch name="timer1"/>
    <echo message="Hello" />
    <stopwatch name="timer1" action="total" />
    <echo message="Total time: ${timer1}" />
  </target>
</project>
```

Output is:

```
Buildfile: /home/[...]/StopwatchTest/build_stopwatch.xml
teststopwatch:
     [echo] Hello
[stopwatch] [timer1: 0.012 sec]
     [echo] Total time: 0.012 sec
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 564 milliseconds
```